# Visio stencil/shape text box is hidden - need shown

Tags: text, shapes, shapesheet, visio-2010

I've downloaded and am using the VNX 5300 stencil/shape from https://download.emc.com/downloads/DL38235_VNX_Visio_Stencil.zip (I had to create a free account to download it).

I can hit F2 to edit the text, as normal, but it will not display.  On other downloaded shapes/stencils, if I right-clicked on the shape/stencil, I would have the option to hide/show shape text, but it doesn't exist on this one.  I have looked in the shapesheet data, and "hide text" is already set to false.  In developer options, the text is not protected.

Is there a way to force the text to display?  I hope to learn how to fix this problem, rather than band-aid it and merely add a second text box.

Answer (score 1):

This stencil was created oddly.  I had to right-click and ungroup from master.  Then I had to, again, right-click and ungroup a second time.  After the two ungroup actions (from its original format--I did NOT group it to anything, whatsoever), I was able to edit the text and see it, but cannot move it.  The shapesheet then showed the "text transform" options so I can pin it, but again, cannot move it to the location I want.

I then had to completely frankenstein and butcher the shapesheet text transform to barely get it moved where I wanted.  Adding a text control handle was not possible.

This is a faulty stencil made by EMC, apparently, as I have not had these problems with any of the other brands' stencils I've downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

**Show / Hide Shape Text using ShapeSheet**

Enable the Developer Tab

- File / Options
- Customize Ribbon
- Check box next to Developer and click OK
- Click on the shape
- On the Developer tab click on **Show ShapeSheet**
- In the ShapeSheet scroll down to the Miscellaneous section
- Change **HideText** from True to False (or False to True if you're
  trying to    hide the text)